# Flutter DatePickerThemeData year attributes not working on current year

Tags: flutter, datepicker, themes

I am displaying a showDatePicker in my app and I would like to have it adjust to my custom themes. When loading the app, it automatically sets the light/dark theme and, depending on the current date, the appropriate seasonal theme.

I've modified every aspect of the DatePicker to match the current theme, except when switching to the yearly mode, the current year is not being modified.

Here is with the year selected:

[image: selected current year]

Here is with a different year selected:

[image: different year selected]

As you can see from this example, the default blue being provided is not the same as the blue that I am grabbing from the current theme. I've tried wrapping the DatePicker in a ThemeData and provide the color scheme instead of using the DatePickerThemeData, but I don't have access to changing more specific options of the DatePicker.

Here is my code. It will change every year option aside from this current year, 2023, but I would like to get it to adjust for that option as well somehow.

```dart
    await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initialDate,
        selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime dateTime) => weekday.contains(dateTime.weekday) &&
                (dateTime.isAfter(
                  initialDate.subtract(
                    const Duration(days: 1),
                  ),
                ))
            ? true
            : false,
        firstDate: first,
        lastDate: last,
        helpText: "Select a Delivery Date:",
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
                child: Theme(
                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                          datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
                              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                              headerBackgroundColor: customSwatch,
                              headerForegroundColor: Colors.white,
                              dayBackgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                                  return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
                                }
                                return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background;
                              }),
                              yearBackgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                                  return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
                                }
                                return Colors.yellow;
                              }),
                              yearForegroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                                  return Colors.white;
                                }
                                return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary;
                              })),
                          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                            floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                  child: child!,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

I've removed the section for dark theme to be more concise as it's the same thing. Any help as to how to change the current year's styling would be very much appreciated, thanks!